# Annotate the parameter of function

Tags: f#

I want to create a function `foo` which get the function `f` and string `s`.
The function apply the function `f` to `s` and return the length of array:

```
let foo (f : (`a -> `b[])) (s : string) =
            let attrs  = f s
            attrs.Length
```

F# compiler doesn't know that all `f` functions return the array of something.
How can I give the hint to compiler ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, the only problem with your snippet is that the backtick  (`` ` `` in your generic type name) should be just a single quote:

```
let foo (f : ('a -> 'b[])) (s : string) =
  let attrs  = f s
  attrs.Length
```

There is another little issue which is that calling `f` with `s` as an argument restricts the type `'a` to `string`, but that's a separate question.

Comment: Also to avoid 'less generic' you can use `'a` type instead of `string`